# AssertionError when trying to render API data using djangorestframwork?

Tags: django, api, django-rest-framework

I am trying to build a function API using djangorestframwork
But I have this error:

```
Cannot apply DjangoModelPermissionsOrAnonReadOnly on a view that does not set `.queryset` or have a `.get_queryset()` method.
```

This is my API function:

```
@api_view(('GET',))
@renderer_classes((TemplateHTMLRenderer, JSONRenderer))
def course_api(request):
    if request.method == 'GET':
        queryset = Course.objects.all()
        serializer = CourseNameSerializers(queryset, many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data, template_name='api.html')
```

When I delete first line and second line another error occurs
and this error is:

```
.accepted_renderer not set on Response
```

Comment: It seems like the `DjangoModelPermissionsOrAnonReadOnly` is only works with the *class-based-views*, whereas you are using *function-based-views*

Comment: But when I search the web I found a lot of developers using function-based-view with djangorestframword as API.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was trying to find what was my problem and i found that I used
`REST_FRAMEWORK in settings.py file`

this is my settings.py for REST_FRAMEWORK

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    # Use Django's standard `django.contrib.auth` permissions,
    # or allow read-only access for unauthenticated users.
    'DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES': [
        'rest_framework.permissions.DjangoModelPermissionsOrAnonReadOnly'
    ]
}
```

I removed these lines of code and the API works fine.